# Scalable Ambient Obscurance rendering issue

Tags: opengl, ssao

I am trying to implement [this SAO algorithm](http://graphics.cs.williams.edu/papers/SAOHPG12/).

I am getting the following result :

[image: result]

I can't figure out why I have the nose on top of the walls, it seems to be a z-buffer issue.

Here are my input values :

```
const float projScale = 100.0;
const float radius = 0.9;
const float bias = 0.0005;
const float intensityDivR6 = pow(radius, 6);
```

I am using the original shader without modifications, except that I disable the usage of mipmaps of the depth buffer.

My depth buffer (on different scene, sorry) :

[image: depth]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should be an issue with the zbuffer linearization or it's not between -1 and 1.

Answer (score 1):

Thank you Bruno, I finally figure out what were the issues.
The first was that I didn't transform my Z correctly, they use a specific pre-pass to make the Z linear and put it between -1 and 1. I was using an incompatible method to do it.

I also had to negate my near and far planes values directly in the projection matrix to compute correctly some uniforms.

Result :
[image: result]

Comment: Can you post the solution please?

I am implementing the same algorithm, and I may face some of the problems you encountered. I did not negate my near/far planes but it seems to work without doing it.
However, whenever my camera is close to an object, I obtaine a wrong self-occlusion (http://i.imgur.com/OWriRrK.png). I am not sure about this but it could be linked to the problem you had.

Comment: You should negate the near and far plane to avoid accumulation of errors that in some situations might seems getting a correct result. I took some times to understand my issues because of that. You have AO on the front corner of your plane because it is not infinite, except that I am not sure that your result is wrong. Have you some other pictures?

Comment: Yes sure, I have some others on the Sponza scene. The scene fits in a bounding sphere with a 23 units radius. The result is quite good : http://i.imgur.com/lXFuOXP.png (you can see the scene settings on the top right). But whenever I increase a bit the radius, I can see the same effect appearing, when I put the camera close, I get self occlusion: 
http://i.imgur.com/TqRaoy0.png

There is something I forgot to mention, my near/far are automatically updated to fit according to what the camera actually see from the sceen.

Comment: Thanks, I succeed to fix it!
I posted my solution as an answer in case someone else has the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem, having visual wrong occlusion, linked to the near/far, so I decided to give you what I've done to fix it.

The problem I had is discribed in a previous comment. I was getting self occlusion, when the camera was close to an object or when the radius was really too big.

If you take a closer look at the conversion from depth buffer value to camera-space value (the `reconstructCSZ` function from the [g3d engine](http://g3d.cs.williams.edu/websvn/filedetails.php?repname=g3d&path=%2FG3D10%2Fdata-files%2Fshader%2FreconstructFromDepth.glsl)), you will see that replacing the depth by 0 will give you the near plane if you work with positive near/far. So, what it means is that every time you will get a tap outside the model, you will get a z component equals to near, which will give you wrong occlusion for fragments having a z close to 0.
You basically have to discard each taps that are located on the near plane, to avoid them being taken into account when comptuing the full contribution.